# How do change my Arduino Uno from an unknown device to a port?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I have an Arduino Uno that I have connected to a servo motor. I used an adapter to plug it into my computer and my computer said "Setting up a device, this will only take a minute". When it was done setting up, I downloaded Arduino IDE and I wrote a code. When I clicked "Upload", I was told that a serial port was not selected. I went to Tools>Port>Arduino Uno. The program then uploaded, I unplugged it and began its process. After I uploaded, I wanted to make a change to my code so I plugged it back in and I heard the Windows *beepboopbeep* sound. I edited the code and tried to upload again and it said that a serial port was not selected. I went to Device Manager and found it under another tab, something like Amtek USB ports. It was labeled as "Unknown Device". I tried to select it but it told me that it couldn't update driver. I looked it up and people said to unplug and replug in another USB port. I tried that 7 times yet it was still "Unknown Device". Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I am using a HP AMD Radeon 7 Processor laptop running Windows 10 and my Arduino is not a copy, it is authentic.

Comment: All USB devices have 1) a manufacture ID & 2) a device ID.  A computer read these and picks a driver to load in.  On a Linux computer (and probably on a Mac) the command "lsusb" will return these ID for all connected devices.  You did not say what type of computer you are using.    Also, you did not say if your Arduino Uno board is  authentic or a copy.   This information may help others find an answer.  Although this is sometimes a tricky subject.  Especially when Windows gets involved.

Comment: Does the arduino IDE show a different COM port to select. The time it worked you said you had selected  `Tools>Port>Arduino Uno`. This is new to me. I would expect a port like COM13 or COM15 or such. Does Windows 10 name their serial ports other than Win7 for example?  What programmer did you choose?  Did you select the right board? (UNO)

Comment: `I used an adapter to plug it into my computer` What kind of adapter? The Ardino Uno just plugs directly into your computer with a USB cable. There should be no "adapter" needed.

Comment: @Majenko I used a USB type B to A adapter.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer i do not remember the COM, the Arduino IDE software that I have open says it is COM3 but won't let me select the port anymore. It automatically chose AVRISP mkll as my programmer.

Comment: it started working now that I found a better USB cable, only problem is that now when I upload the code, it does not run

Comment: Then,  if the upload ends with no error messages, the code itself may have errors. Do you understand, how the code works? If you copied it from the internet, try to understand, what the code does. Hopefully there is a little explanation coming with it. If you are complete new to programming, look at the basic sides (e.g. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/ ). -- Perhaps you'll find the error. If not, it's a good opportunity to ask here a new question. People can help you the most, if you add your code, explain what you've done and say what you expect and what not works as you expected it.